# Pass dynamic array to function requiring type double[]?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to use an interface in C with a function `foo` that has the following type

```
void foo(double x[]);
```

However the array `x` that I want to pass to this function is too large for stack memory. Is there a way to pass a dynamic array to `foo`, or increase the size of stack memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function expects `double []` it is equivalent to `double *` since arrays decay into pointers. However note, that there is no way how your function could find out the size of this array since `sizeof` would return the size of pointer. You should pass the size as well:

```
void foo(double x[], int size) {
    ...
}

int main(void) {
    const int N = 10000;
    double *x = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    foo(x, N);
    free(x);    // don't forget to clean up
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function in the interface also has arguments for the size of the array, I just left that out for clarity.

Comment: @DavidPfau: Ah, ok :) In that case just dynamically allocate your array using `malloc` and just pass it to this function without worries.

Answer (score 1):

In a function signature, `double x[]` is equivalent to `double *x`. You're passing a pointer anyway, and a pointer doesn't care whether it points at an object on the heap or an object on the stack. Just allocate your array in whatever way is appropriate (e.g. using `malloc` if it's too large for the stack) and pass the resulting pointer to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will work fine. Array parameters are not copied to the stack, they're always passed as a pointer. The function declaration you wrote is actually equivalent to:

```
void foo(double *x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate the array on the heap using malloc. The problem is not with the function. Rather the problem is where you allocate the array that you pass to the function. So long as you allocate the array on the heap, you will not overflow your stack.

Comment: Not an answer to the question he asked.

Comment: @barmer are you sure?

Comment: Well, everyone gave pretty much the same answer pretty much instantly.

Comment: But basically my question was: how are `double []` and `double *` handled differently in function declarations in C/C++, and I guess the answer is: they aren't.

Comment: Yeah. The stack overflow is at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass an array into a function it degenerates into a pointer to the base type, pointing at the first element.

it never passes all the values on the stack.